# Concavity of distance function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or determinant of $(x^T \cdot x)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

I would like to compute the concavity of the distance function in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $ f(x) =- \Vert x \Vert $ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\nabla_xf=- \frac{x}{\Vert x \Vert}$. And $$-\operatorname{Hess}_x(f)=\frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert} E_n + \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert^3} (x_i\cdot x_j)_{ij}.$$

The function f is concave if $\operatorname{Hess}f$ is negative definite. Therefore I want to compute the Determinant of the second matrix. Does anyone has sugestions how to do so?

I want to have a more subtle result than "just" concavity. 
I want to compute **how concave the distance function** is on $B_r(0)$ (depending on $r$) in the sense of $\lambda$-concavity. 
A function is $\lambda$ concave on a riem. Manifold if for every unit speed geodesic $\gamma$ between $x$ and $y$ the function $f\circ \gamma(t) - \lambda t^2$ is concave for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Reason behind computation:**

For a nonnegatively curved space $M$ the distance function $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial C)$ is concave for every convex subset $C$ on $C \setminus \partial C$. How much better does it get for balls in the eulidean plane? How much more ($\lambda$)-concave is $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial B_r(0))=r- \Vert x \Vert$?

Comment: I think it would be easier to use the definition of convexity (and the triangle inequality) to directly show that $-f$ is convex.

Comment: I wonder can we differentiate the distance function. It seems to not be differentiable.

Comment: I tried to do it with the following definition of concavity: A function is convex if for every shortest path $\gamma(t)$ from $x$ to $y$ for $x,y \in B_r(p)$. The function $f \circ \gamma(t)$ is concave. 
This means you have to compute $(f\circ \gamma)'' \geq 0$. Given this function is differentiable. However you would need to find the minimum of this function. So you need to compute 4 derivatives of $f \circ \gamma$.
I wonder if there is a more geometric way, to get the result easier.

Comment: The distance function is differentiable exept at $0$.

Comment: If you're looking for _strict_ concavity (negative definite Hessian), you'll be disappointed. The function $f(x)=-\|x\|$ has one zero eigenvalue everywhere it's differentiable, because $f$ decreases linearly along the direction radially away from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a slightly different result then you when I calculate the Hessian. Starting with

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}
$$

I get that

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} = -\frac{\|x\|^2 - x_i^2}{\|x\|^3}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = \frac{x_i x_j}{\|x\|^3}
$$

Therefore, we should have that

$$
\text{Hess}_x(f) = -\frac{1}{\|x\|}\left(I - \bar{x}\bar{x}^T\right),
$$

where $\bar{x} = x/\|x\|$. From here you can show that the Hessian is negative definite as follows. Let $y$ be any nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$
y^T \text{Hess}_x(f) y = -\frac{1}{\|x\|}[y^T y - (y^T\bar{x})^2] 
$$

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have that

$$
|y^T\bar{x}|^2 \leq (y^Ty)\cdot(\bar{x}^T\bar{x}) = y^Ty
$$

Thus $y^Ty - (y^T\bar{x})^2 \geq 0$ and hence $y^T \text{Hess}_x(f) y \leq 0$.

Comment: True, but I am looking for a more subtle result, which I did not state before. I will correct that in a minute. 
I actually want to know how concave the distance function is on $B_r(0)$ in the sense of $\lambda$ concavity.